# How do I mimic the build and deploy functionality in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio via a script?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, amazon-web-services

I have a .NET solution with several different projects.  Each of them I have now set up via the AWS Toolkit so I can just right click and hit "Redeploy to AWS..." but what I would like to do create a script (PowerShell maybe?) that builds and deploys all of my projects automatically.

I know there is a CLI version of the AWS Toolkit called awsdeploy.exe but it doesn't seem like that will perform the compilation and archiving of a project like the AWS Toolkit plugin does.

How do I mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm currently tackling this question at work, with partial success. What I have found is that you can do the packaging with msbuild, and then deploy with awsdeploy.

For example, if I have a visual studio solution call bas, with two projects, foo and bar, and I want to deploy bar, then I first package bar with msbuild.

> msbuild bar/bar.csproj /t:Package /p:PackageLocation=barPackage.zip

This should create a package call barPackage.zip under the bar directory. If you don't find it, look at the msbuild output as it should let you know where it was created.

Now that we have the package, we can deploy. Awsdeploy needs a configuration file. It's just a file that contains key value pairs of the form "key = value". There is an example file in a directory called Samples\, in the same directory where the awsdeploy.exe is located.

If you are using visual studio there is an option for creating the config file while deploying to aws.

More info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-deployment-tool.html#deployment-tool-configuration-file-format

Let's assume we have a configuration file called deployConfig.txt then we can call awsdeploy like so

> awsdeploy /r deployConfig.txt

Note that the /r is for redeploy. This assumes that you already have an environment running.

If you don't want to put credential inside the file, you can also do.

> awsdeploy /r /DAWSAccessKey=stuff /DAWSSecretKey=stuff deployCon

In general anything we don't want on the file we can specify on the command like by adding /Dsomething=stuff. As you can see above to specify AWSSecretKey we do /DAWSSecretKey=stuff.

The visual studio generated file does not list the location of the package so what I've been doing is

> awsdeploy /r /DAWSAccessKey=stuff /DAWSSecretKey=stuff /DDeploymentPackage=bar/bar.zip deployConfig.txt

This almost works for me. But sadly it doesn't quite do the trick. It deploys the package, and I can see the environment trying to load it but fails at some point. I don't know why it's failing to load it. It loads it fine when I deploy it from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we're handling it.  All of this runs on our CI server:

Step 1 - build web deploy package with msbuild:

> msbuild website.csproj /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=website.zip /p:Configuration=Release
>   /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"

Step 2 - deploy with awsdeploy:

> awsdeploy.exe /DAWSAccessKey=**** /DAWSSecretKey=**** /r config.txt

config.txt:

```
DeploymentPackage = .\website.zip 
AWSProfileName = ****** 
Region = us-east-1 
Template = ElasticBeanstalk 
UploadBucket = ***********
Application.Name = *********** 
Environment.Name = ***********
```

Comment: Can you share exact ps1 file example? I am trying to get it running but all the time awsdeploy gives me an error about input syntax error.

Comment: This is the error:
10:45:26  "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool\awsdeploy.exe" -v -DApplication.Name="<name>" -DDeploymentPackage="C:\<path>\<archive>.zip" -DAWSAccessKey="<key" -DAWSSecretKey="<key>" -r "C:\<path>\awsebscfg.txt"
10:45:26  powershell.exe : Usage: awsdeploy [-options] configFile

10:45:26  At C:\workspace\rc\server\feature_path@tmp\durable-3328e0b9\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1